# Change FPS of Sprite-Kit Game?

Tags: swift, ios8, sprite-kit, frame-rate

Is it possible to change the FPS of a Sprite-Kit game? If it is possible, how can I implement this into my code?

For example, if a user wants to conserve battery the game can change the FPS from 60 (default value) to 30 or 20.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `SKView`'s `frameInterval` to the desired value.

Ref: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKView/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKView/frameInterval

Setting the interval to 2 will cause half the default frame rate. (It is an integer though so it appears that the only option would be to cut the frame rate by half, third, fourth, etc.

Comment: iOS 10.0 and later use preferredFramesPerSecond instead!

Answer (score 1):

```
let gameView = SKView()

if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    gameView.preferredFramesPerSecond = 30
} else {
    gameView.frameInterval = 2 //Deprecated
}
```